# TextAngular config with different views

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if i could change textangular configuration with different views.
Currently I can only do a standard config.
Any ideas? cheers

```
module.config(function($provide){
          $provide.decorator('taTools', ['$delegate', function(taTools){ 

            taTools.fontName.options = [
                {name: 'Amatic Regular', css: 'amatic_scregular'},
                {name: 'Amatic Bold', css: 'amatic_scbold'}
            ]; 
            return taTools;
        }]);
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some more details as to what you mean by "different views" please?

Comment: Hi Simeon, I was looking to change taTools.fontName.options in the controller if possible. Different views - my project had a side menu with different types of pages (different sizes for textarea - using angular templates). I needed also to change some allowed fonts in the toolbar for different pages. cheers

Comment: OK, I think I understand that now, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently textAngular doesn't support view templates for the toolbar. You can get around this by either defining multiple versions of your tool and using the `ta-toolbar` attribute to pick which buttons are displayed.

Or if you are only using one version of the editor you could use the add/remove tool functions in the textAngularManager. https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular.js#L1853-L1887

Comment: Cheers Simeon. I'm in the right direction now, textAngularManager did it. Thanks